# Dumping data from incoming NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, networkstream

Is there a way to somehow skip/dump X bytes of data from incoming NetworkStream? You can't `Seek` it or `Position` it, so it seems only way is to copy it to other stream or just read it and dump it afterwards.

Currently I am using `ReadAsync()` method to read the stream.

Comment: You are correct, unless the protocol and endpoint somehow supports it the only way to move it along is to read and dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must read all of the data in a `NetworkStream`.  If you need to skip data, you can read and ignore it, but you have to read it before it moves forward.  This is because `NetworkStream` is abstracting a TCP socket stream of data-- and there is nothing in TCP that says to skip bytes-- it's just a firehose of binary data coming at you.  Protocols on top of TCP, such as FTP or HTTP, may implement concepts that would allow you to position within a file or object, but `NetworkStream` isn't aware of all that-- it's just letting you get the socket data as it comes.

If you have need of a Stream to abstract the seeking functions so you can pass it to some code that requires a seekable stream, you could build your own `Stream` class that wraps `NetworkStream` that implements `Seek` and or `Position`.  It of course, under the table, would have to read and ignore the sections you used `Seek` or `Position` to bypass; and unless you buffer it, you wouldn't be able to implement `Seek` or `Position` backwards.